# How do we use the piped command in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, pipe

This is the command -

```
$ find /var/opt/ -type f -mtime -1 -print0 | du -s |cut -f1    
498172
```

When I run from the command line in Linux it gives output - the size.
I want to run the same command from Perl and need to capture the output in a variable.

I tried this:

```
my $cmd = "find /var/opt/ -type f -mtime -1 -print0 | du -s |cut -f1";
my @output = `$cmd`;
```

I am receiving an entirely different output - '\20' instead of **498172**.

Can someone help me with what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can also calculate the size in the Perl script without needing to call the external command `du`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $size = 0;
my $dir = '/var/opt';
find(sub {-f $_ &&  -M _ < 1 && do {$size += -s _ }}, $dir);
say int($size/1024), " KiB";
```

Note this reports the apparent size, not the disk usage. See [How to get the actual directory size (out of du)?](https://superuser.com/q/602818/278134) for more information.